# Setting data in a data expression

Tags: webassembly

In the WebAssembly text format, every `data` expression I've seen provides data as a string, as in `"hello"`. But the spec says that the last argument of `data` can be a `concat((*)*)`, which apparently represents a concatenation of data elements.

Does anyone have an example of this? I can't find anything helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A data segment can be written with multiple strings, which are simply concatenated:

```
(data (offset (i32.const 0))
  "... part 1 ..."
  "... part 2 ..."
  "... part 3 ..."
)
```

The only reason for this feature is to enable splitting the string over multiple lines (cf. string literals in C).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand spec in `data` section last argument is size of current block. As `data` uses `linear memory possible` you can guess size of the string and return `concat` of strings

```
(module
  (import "imp" "log" (func $log (param i32 i32)))
  (memory (import "imp" "mem") 1)
  (func $writeHi
    i32.const 0
    i32.const 13
    call $log
  )
  (data (i32.const 0) "hello")
  (data (i32.const 5) " ")
  (data (i32.const 6) "world")
  (export "writeLog" (func $writeHi))
)
```

with this js

```
function consoleLogString(memory, offset, length) {
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, offset, length);
        var string = new TextDecoder('utf8').decode(bytes);
        console.log(string);
    }
    const memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 2 });
    const consoleLogStringWrapper = memory => (offset, length) => consoleLogString(memory, offset, length);
    var importObj = {
        imp : {
            mem: memory,
            log: consoleLogStringWrapper(memory)
        }
    };

    const wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule, importObj);
    const { writeHi } = wasmInstance.exports;
    writeHi();
```

will return `hello world`, you can check on [wat2wasm](https://cdn.rawgit.com/WebAssembly/wabt/aae5a4b7/demo/wat2wasm/)